# Change file format to baracuda in mariadb server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cpanel

I am using namecheap shared hosting and I cannot change my file_format to baracuda. I actually need to change my row_format for tables to dynamic or compressed which is available only in baracuda file format.

I am currently using the following query:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = "Barracuda";<br>
```

Error:

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.
```

I searched online but couldn't find any other solution. I asked the namecheap support to give me the "super privilage" and they say I already have it. But, apparently, my DB user doesn't.
What can I do?

Comment: When you execute `show grants;` what's the result?

Comment: @fancyPants 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mounqfgc\_santosh`.* TO 'mounqfgc'@'localhost'
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mounqfgc'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*password'

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

[Manual entry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_all):

> The ALL or ALL PRIVILEGES privilege specifier is shorthand. It stands for “all privileges available at a given privilege level” (except GRANT OPTION). For example, granting ALL at the global or table level grants all global privileges or all table-level privileges.

You have all privileges on the level of your schema, but not for the whole server. To change the file_format, they would have to grant you the super privilege on the global level like this:

```
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO foo@bar;
```

But I doubt they will give it to you. You can ask them however to change it for you. It does not make changes to already exisiting tables so they shouldn't have a problem with it. You will have to upgrade a table to the new file format with statements like

```
ALTER TABLE foo FORCE;
```